# Does using pivot in sql server change the table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I executed the command below, and I'm wondering if I've changed anything on the table as it says rows affected.

I'm new to using pivot and I tried following this:
http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php

I executed this command, and at the end it said:

```
(1752 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'W'.
>   State:37000,Native:156,Origin:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   State:37000,Native:105,Origin:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Code:

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT 
    @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(school_name as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast(school_name as varchar)+ ']')
FROM Education
GROUP BY school_name

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '
SELECT 
    Applicant.legal_first_name
    ,Applicant.legal_last_name
    ,Education.school_name
from 
    Applicant
inner join 
    Application on application.applicant_id = applicant.applicant_id
inner join 
    Education on education.application_id = application.application_id
order by applicant.legal_first_name
PIVOT
(
    MAX(school_name)
    FOR [school_name]
    IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Try executing the simple `select 1` and reviewing the resulting Messages tab.

Comment: I can see there are lot of temp tables created in the example you quoted. Are you sure you didn't create any of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(school_name as varchar) + ']', '[' + cast(school_name as varchar) + ']')
from Education
group by school_name

set @query = '
select *
from 
(
select 
    Applicant.legal_first_name
    ,Applicant.legal_last_name
    ,Education.school_name
from 
    Applicant
inner join 
    Application on application.applicant_id = applicant.applicant_id
inner join 
    Education on education.application_id = application.application_id
order by applicant.legal_first_name
)
AS S
PIVOT
(
    MAX(school_name)
    FOR [school_name]
    IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS P
'
execute(@query)
```

I have try this code on [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Address]

```
use AdventureWorks2012;
go

declare @columns nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(City as varchar) + ']', '[' + cast(City as varchar) + ']')
from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Address]
group by [City]

set @query = '
SELECT *
from
(
SELECT [City]
FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Address]
) as P1

PIVOT
(
    COUNT([City])
    FOR [City]
    IN (' + @columns + ')
) as P2
'
execute (@query)
```